# Wocommerce: How to stop scrolling to checkout bottom - on update_checkout trigger

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

WooCommerce scrolls to `.form.checkout` if there are any errors on the checkout form, it's good.
But when I trigger update_checkout function by:

```
$(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
```

It updates checkout form and scroll window to the bottom - payments and shipping box.

I tought that I found solution, but it doesnt work - It make thing worse, scroll to errors notices on checkout form error not wokring but keep scrolling to the bottom of the checkout form :

```
    jQuery( document ).ajaxComplete( function() {
        if ( jQuery( 'body' ).hasClass( 'woocommerce-checkout' ) || jQuery( 'body' ).hasClass( 'woocommerce-cart' ) ) {
            jQuery( 'html, body' ).stop();
        }
    } );
```

Comment: That doesn't happen normally when using `$(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');`, so there is something else involved that can be another customization made by you, your theme or a plugin…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I use Browsersync which caused it, withut browsersync proxy it works without any problems